# SQL query from 3 different tables.

Tags: mysql, sql, database

First I want you to show my tables:

Table Users

```
CREATE TABLE Users(
   EMAIL VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL);
```

Table Actions

```
CREATE TABLE Actions
    IDACCION INT NOT NULL,
    ACCION VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);
```

Table UserAction

```
CREATE TABLE UserAction(
    EMAIL VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    IDACCION INT NOT NULL,
    DATETIME DATE NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (IDACCION) REFERENCES Actions(IDACCION),
    FOREIGN KEY (EMAIL) REFERENCES Users(EMAIL),
    PRIMARY KEY (IDACCION, EMAIL, DATETIME));
```

Then, I need to get the actions (ACCION from Actions) and DATETIME (DATETIME from UserAction) asociated with him, where the condition is that email (from User) be the same as Action email. Is it possible?

If is not possible, I can move DATETIME to Action table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to structure your tables, your Users table does not have a Primary key and don't seem to have any purpose on an application, for this query doesn't even need Users table.

```
SELECT a.ACCION, ua.DATETIME FROM Actions a
INNER JOIN UserAction ua on a.IDACCION = ua.IDACCION
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include the line..Email is primary key of users and idaccion is primary key of action

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
 a.accion,
 ua.datetime
from 
 users u,
 actions a,
 useraction ua
where
 u.email=ua.email
 and ua.idaccion=a.idaccion;
```

Comment: Please don't use archaic syntax when answering questions.  Use explicit `JOIN`.

Comment: Please research the JOIN clauses, this will help you.

Comment: It works. Now I need 1 more thing. How can I compare DATETIME with two passed as argument? Here is the date format: 'yyyy/MM/dd hh24:mi:ss'... I need to show all cases where the date is between the other ones passed as arguments.

Comment: I agree with @Gordon - being explicit makes it clear for everyone, especially those still learning the basics.

Comment: For example. I have 5 dates on my bbdd..(5/11/15 21:09:00, 5/11/15 21:09:00, etc) , and have to show this who are between the two dates passed as arguments

Answer (score 1):

Note that `datetime` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html) for MySQL.

You can try the following:

```
SELECT aa.ACCION, bb.`DATETIME`
FROM Actions AS aa
INNER JOIN UserAction AS bb
ON aa.IDACCION = bb.IDACCION
INNER JOIN Users AS cc
ON bb.EMAIL = cc.EMAIL;
```

Answer (score 0):

In answer to the second question, that of comparing dates, T-SQL contains a function called DATEDIFF that will compare dates rather well. I suggest you look at the Microsoft Developer Network article [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx).